# Textbullet sharelatex

Tags: itemize

```
\programming{{NetBackup $\textbullet$ VM-Ware  $\textbullet$ CTRL-M / 5}, {C $\textbullet$ C++ $\textbullet$ Python  / 3.5}, {LayoutCAD $\textbullet$ CorelCAD $\textbullet$ OriginPro / 5}}
```

For this code I am not able to get textbullets which I saw previously, please explain

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX throws a warning because a *text* symbol is used in math mode:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textbullet invalid in math mode
```

Just remove the math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  NetBackup \textbullet\ VM-Ware  \textbullet\ CTRL-M 5\\
  C \textbullet\ C++ \textbullet\ Python 3.5\\
  LayoutCAD \textbullet\ CorelCAD \textbullet\ OriginPro 5
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]